# I need to replace tablelayout with datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make autosized datagridview without adding it before that on the form. Now my code is with `tableLayout`, but I need to replace it with `DataGridView`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataManipulator.columnCheckedList.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {
   labels[i] = new Label();
            labels[i].Text = visibleColumns[i];

            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(labels[i]);

            txtBox[i] = new TextBox();
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(txtBox[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(2, m++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txtBox[i]);
            getSqlColumnTypes += $"'{labels[i].Text}'";
            SqlDataAdapter sqladapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"{getSqlColumnTypes}", loginForm.connection = new SqlConnection($"Server = {loginForm.serverName.Text }; Database = { loginForm.DBNames.SelectedItem}; Trusted_Connection = True"));
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            sqladapter.Fill(dt);
            labels[i] = new Label();
            labels[i].Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

            tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, k++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataManipulator.columnCheckedList.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
  {
       addRecordDataGridView.Rows.Add(visibleColumns[i]);
       getSqlColumnTypes += $"'{visibleColumns[i]}'";
       SqlDataAdapter sqladapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"{getSqlColumnTypes}", loginForm.connection = new SqlConnection($"Server = {loginForm.serverName.Text }; Database = { loginForm.DBNames.SelectedItem}; Trusted_Connection = True"));
       DataSet dt = new DataSet();
       sqladapter.Fill(dt);
       addRecordDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
       addRecordDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Tag = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   }
```